# What is Instagram deep link in React Native for iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, instagram, deep-linking

I need to open the Instagram Direct Message from React Native app and send a text to a selected contact after opening in Instagram.

I already found the way to open Whatsapp and send a message to selected contact using:

```
Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text='+text);
```

Also I found this for Instagram which is not working:

```
Linking.openURL('instagram://library?OpenInEditor=1&LocalIdentifier=${identifier}');
```

Does anyone know how to do that? (I know there are some sharing tools but I don't need to use them)